NextJS loading skeleton for lottie file?
In NextJS I have this client component:
'use client'

import { DotLottiePlayer } from "@dotlottie/react-player";
import '@dotlottie/react-player/dist/index.css';

export default function Food() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DotLottiePlayer
        src="/food.lottie"
        autoplay
        loop
      />
    </div>
  )
}

Currently I am using it on a page where it creates a UI popping effect into the screen as it becomes ready like this.
The component that imports it looks like a generic component:
export default function FoodServices() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <div>
        Maria loved the vibrant colors of fresh fruits and vegetables, filling her plate with a rainbow of nutritious goodness each day. One morning, she discovered a local farmer's market, where she found the sweetest strawberries and the crispest lettuce she'd ever tasted. As she enjoyed her healthy meals, she felt more energetic and happier, knowing she was nourishing her body with nature's best offerings.
        {/* other stuff */}
      </div>
      <Food />
    </Container>
  )
}

I'm certain the Suspense API doesn't work in this case. How can I use a skeleton till the client component is displayed?
